# FULLTEX Search on two column of Different Table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Can anyone help me to find the query for fulltext search?
I have two columns Product and Generic.

Table-Product:

```
1. ProductID (Integer)
2. GenericID (Integer)-FK
3. Product_Name (Varchar)
```

And in Table-Generic:

```
1. GenericID (Integer)
2. Generic_Name (Varchar)
```

What I need is to search the input string with the combined name of both Product_Name and Generic_Name.

my sample query is given below

```
 SELECT 
 prod.ProductID AS ID,
 generic.Generic_Name AS genericName,
 prod.Product_Name AS packageName
 FROM
 Product prod
 INNER JOIN
 Generic generic ON prod.GenericID  = generic.GenericID 
 WHERE
 MATCH (prod.Product_Name ,generic.Generic_Name) AGAINST('+acb* +ace* +serr*  +para*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY prod.Product_Name  ASC
```

It doesn't work because the columns are in different tables.

Answer (score 0):

FULLTEXT search operations each use a FULLTEXT index. That index can only be on one table.

So, you could try using two fulltext search operations...

```
WHERE (  
  match(prod.Product_Name) against('+acb* +ace* +serr*  +para*' in boolean mode)
  OR
  match(generic.Generic_Name) against('+acb* +ace* +serr*  +para*' in boolean mode)
)
```

Or, for best performance and result-set ranking, you could build a new `name` table like this

```
GenericId     NOT a primary key
IsGeneric     1 or 0
Name          either Product_Name or Generic_Name
```

You would construct this table from the union of the names in your other two tables. For example, it might contain

```
  4321  0   Advil
  4321  0   Motrin
  4321  1   Ibuprofen
  4322  0   Coumadin
  4322  1   Warfarin
```

Then, a query like this would do the trick

```
 select  prod.ProductID  AS ID,
         generic.Generic_Name AS genericName,
         prod.Product_Name  AS packageName
    FROM Product prod
   INNER JOIN Generic generic ON prod.GenericID  = generic.GenericID
   INNER JOIN Name ON Name.GenericID = prod.GenericID
   WHERE MATCH(Name.Name) AGAINST('+acb* +ace* +serr*  +para*' in boolean mode)
   ORDER BY prod.Product_Name  ASC
```

The second alternative is more work to program. But, because it puts both tradenames and generic names into a single fulltext index, it will be faster and it is likely to give better results.